# A sequence of functions that need (benefit from) parallelisation

Tags: python, parallel-processing, concurrent.futures

I have a rather broad question about launching parallel tasks. I've never done it before, and I'm struggling with maintaining the overall structure of my code. When it comes to 1 function, the task is fairly straightforward, I guess.

---

### The problem

If I have more than 1 function, let's say 3 or 4, some of which have to be parallelised, it gets confusing quite quickly.

---

### An example

Here is an example of a **worker function** `worker_1` and a function that utilizes this **worker** to do tasks in parallel `parallelise_1`:

```
def worker_1(arg_A, arg_B):
    ... # do something
    return something

def parallelise_1(arg_A, arg_B):
    my_list = []
    
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(worker_1, arg_A, arg_B)
        
        for result in results:
            my_list.append(result)
            
    return my_list
```

How I've managed to make it work:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    AA = parallelise_1(arg_A, arg_B) # (1)
    BB = parallelise_2(AA, arg_C) # (2)
    CC = some_other_function(BB, arg_D) # (3)
```

(1) - function `parallelise_1` has to be parallelised;

(2) - function `parallelise_2` has to be parallelised, **using the output of** `parallelise_1` **as an argument**;

(3) - function `some_other_function` doesn't need to be parallelised, **but it uses the output of** `parallelise_2` **as an argument**.

---

### My question

Although this solution works, I find it really clumsy and inconvenient, especially when a project gets more complicated. Everything has to be inside the `if __name__ == '__main__'` idiom. Are there any ways it can be done more coherent, cleaner? I would appreciate any input!

P.S. I'am using Windows, not Linux.

Comment: It's simple. If one task depends on the results of another, the two cannot be parallelized. You might be able to achieve some parallelization if you can divide the work up into chunks that can be processed concurrently because they do not depend on one another. Off-topic: putting stuff in **bold** like that does not make your question clearer.

Comment: @ martineau Thanks for your response. Probably my question was not very clear. I am not expecting `parallelise_1` and `parallelise_2` to run simultaneously. The goal is to utilise multiprocessing within `parallelise_1` and get the output. Following that, feed the output to `parallelise_2` and utilise multiprocessing within `parallelise_2`. So, I'm just trying to find a more "proper" solution as opposed to mine (that's worked as intended).